# FileNotFoundException : class path resource cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

I have a java project with a parent pom.xml. It has multiple sub-projects, each having it's pom.xml separately. Now in one such sub-project, **SubProjectA**, I have a `context-A.xml` in which I am importing `context-B.xml` like this:

`<import resource="classpath:com/mycompany/context-B.xml" />`

This `context-B.xml` is present in another sub-project (different than **SubProjectA**) at the path : `SubProjectB/src/main/resources/com/mycompany/context-B.xml`

This throws me:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/mycompany/context-B.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

I am not sure how this can be resolved.

**Edit:**
The directory structure is like this:

```
|MainProject
|
|----SubProjectA
|--------src/main/resources/com/mycompany/context-A.xml
|--------pom.xml
|
|
|----SubProjectB
|--------src/main/resources/com/mycompany/context-B.xml
|--------pom.xml
|
|
|----pom.xml
```

Comment: To get help you need to show the directory tree and where are SubProjectA and SubProjectB in the tree

Comment: Add all relevant info to the question please.

Comment: Added directory tree in the question.

Comment: Try this path: `main/resources/com/mycompany/context-B.xml` (I can't check it now)